# Does Omnibus require Root access to run?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

Can I use Gitlab Omnibus without root access? I do understand installing it requires root access but once it is installed, could its processes run without root access?

If it is not possible with omnibus, is it possible to both install and **run** Gitlab from source without root access.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you manage to install from source without root, you might run into some trouble later. "Since installations from source don't have Runit, Sidekiq can't be terminated and its memory usage will grow over time."
see http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/install/installation.html first paragraph

Comment: We do understand this situation; however; at the moment we are only interested in finding out if we could run Gitlab without root access. Thanks.